# One-way journey to another star boosted by mirrors

Tags: story-identification, novel, spaceship, space-exploration

A book about a group of people travelling to another star on a one way trip. They are boosted out of the solar system by re-purposed military mirrors. They have a robotic helper that looks like a Christmas tree. There are sequels that detail their exploration of the star system.

Comment: duplicate target's question is newer but has details more likely to be unique

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is Robert Forward's "[Flight of the Dragonfly](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/263496.Flight_of_the_Dragonfly)", which was later expanded and retitled "Rocheworld", published 1985.

Dr. Forward actually invented the interstellar mirror and laser system in his AAAS paper *AFAL TR-87-070, Advanced Space Propulsion Study - Antiproton and Beamed Power Propulsion, Appendix A - Beamed Power Propulsion To The Stars*.

According to the introduction to the novel, the idea of a Christmas bush robot was "jointly conceived" by Forward and Austrian roboticist Has Moravec.

> The "hands" of the Christmas Bush have capabilities that go way beyond
>   that of the human hand. The Christmas Bush can stick a "hand" inside a
>   delicate piece of equipment, and using its lasers as a light source
>   and its detectors as eyes, rearrange the parts inside for a near
>   instantaneous repair. The Christmas Bush also has the ability to
>   detach portions of itself to make smaller motiles. These can walk up
>   the walls and along the ceilings with the tiny cilia holding onto
>   microscopic cracks in the surface. The smaller twigs on the Christmas
>   Bush are capable of very rapid motion. In free fall, these rapidly
>   beating twigs allow the motile to propel itself through the air. The
>   speed of motion of the smaller cilia is rapid enough that the motiles
>   can generate sound and thus can talk directly with the humans. Each
>   astronaut in the crew has a small subtree or "imp" that stays with him
>   or her to act as the communication link to the main computer. Most of
>   the crew have the tiny imp ride on their shoulder, although some of
>   the women prefer to keep theirs in their hairdo. In addition to acting
>   as the communication link to the computer, the imps also act as health
>   monitors and personal servants. They are the ideal solution to the
>   perennial problem of spacesuits ... scratching an itchy nose. The imps
>   go into the spacesuit with the humans, and more than one human life
>   was saved by an imp detecting and repairing a suit failure or patching
>   a leak. In fact, there are two computer motiles with each suited
>   human. The personal one that stays with the human, and the spacesuit
>   motile that stays with the suit. This motile is usually outside in the
>   life-support backpack, but can worm its way inside through the air
>   supply hose

.

Comment: The "Christmas bush" robot sounds like the robots in *Interstellar.*